# А что, ассоциации заработали уже?

Tags: обсуждение, ассоциация-вопросов

Я видел несколько вопросов относительно ассоциаций, но они все датированы 2016 - 2017-м годом. Как я понял, механизм ассоциаций предложили на enSO, а потом задвинули в дальний ящик. Но тут пару дней назад я увидел комментарий к моему ответу, из которого следует, что они уже работают: [Как в oracle в функции count вернуть ноль, если нет данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989173/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-oracle-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-count-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85/989213#989213)

Там справа появился связанный вопрос. Можно уточнить, как связи работают? Они устанавливаются только внутри ruSO? Потому что год назад был похожий случай. Я задавал тут вопрос, не получил на него ответа, задал его на enSO, получил ответ там, перевел, написал здесь, поставил ссылку-ассоциацию - и до сих пор ничего. Вот вопрос: [Как скомбинировать несколько преобразований XSLT?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852019/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-xslt)

Comment: Там же в [комменте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989173/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-oracle-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-count-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85/989213#comment1670080_989213) ссылку дали. Вот оно и связало.

Comment: Ну про ссылки-то я и так знаю. Механизм ассоциаций предлагали сделать похожим образом - постишь в комментарии ссылку, движок сам ее подхватывает. Я думал, движку пофиг, на какой сайт ставить ассоциацию.

Comment: @Dmitriy, не в лбюбом комменте, а в определённом. И задумывалось как раз не так - это временное решение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы путаете связанные вопросы и ассоциации.

Внутри сайта связи работали и работают. Для этого достаточно наличия ссылки на другой вопрос в теле вопроса/ответа/комментария.

Кросс-сайтовые ассоциации <s>так и не сделали.</s> сделали, но зависит вроде как от локали браузера и работает только в одну сторону (с enSO на ruSO) (см комментарии vp_arth ниже).

Comment: `так и не сделали` - вроде цепляются через комментарии же

Comment: @vp_arth ну так руками же, кто во что горазд? *видел кто-то и в теле вопроса внизу пишет*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63447/2110496 https://imgur.com/5Rkl3qp.png

Comment: @vp_arth у меня такой плашки нет. Неужели сделали, но не всем?

Comment: Зависит от локали браузера. Мб, от navigator.language, ибо зачем нам посетители не говорящие по русски?

Comment: @vp_arth интересно, если у меня англ. браузер, то почему мне не показывает ассоциацию с ruSO на enSO

Comment: Обратную никто не делал. Нам важно чтобы русскоязычные пользователи приходили к нам с enSO (который гуглится лучше =) )

Comment: @vp_arth, они делаются руками через конфиг. Не знаю, насколько часто Николас обновляет ассоциации.

Comment: Круто, в том вопросе, который я задавал на enSO, тоже есть такая плашка.