# Что случилось с инструментом связывания вопросов?

Tags: обсуждение, мета

Как сейчас помню, много лет назад пропихивал тему:
[Связь между вопросами на разных языках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347/%d0%a1%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85)

И если память мне не лжёт, то это даже было реализовано в движке.

Инструмент убрали или у меня мало кармы?

Comment: Всё так же работает в ручном режиме. Только в другую сторону и в зависимости от языка браузера.

Comment: А где кнопка для его использования? Не помню. Хотя наверно кармы не хватает.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4500/ https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/ https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4409/ https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9278/